# Unable to start activity java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android

I am trying to run activity. unfortunately we are getting below error. It seem there is some inflating layout issue. Please assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Base activity xml : http://pastie.org/10848446

Base activity java : http://pastie.org/10848447

Login activity xml : http://pastie.org/10848450

Login activity java : http://pastie.org/10848454

Custom font type face: http://pastie.org/10848460

Custom Button : http://pastie.org/10848461

Comment: What is line number 12 in Login xml code?

Comment: in login.xml height of RelativeLayout should be wrap_content. 
and no need to use RelativeLayout as a parent layout, instead make ScrollView a parent layout if you are not doing anything outside scrollView.

Comment: it is relative layout  with height and width.

Comment: layout="@layout/app_bar" post the app bar layout

Comment: There seems some issue with `CustomTypefacedButton`. Where and how that is used ?

Comment: I have changed to wrap_content. Still getting the error.

Comment: issue of customtypefaced button

Comment: post your customtypefacedbutton code

Comment: added customtypefacedbutton code

Comment: where you have use customtypefacedbutton code ? I can see only one button sign_in_button in your code which is not customized.

Comment: updated my code with error log

Answer (score 0):

Check for these class `Error inflating class com.app.nbhc.utilities.CustomTypefacedButton`

Comment: Where have you used this class in xml.

Comment: Could you please post your full xml file for login. I cannot see sign-in button

Comment: I think in xml file you have set the custom button i.e `com.app.nbhc.utilities.CustomTypefacedButton` and in java file you are casting sign-in button to Button, which may be wrong. You have to cast it to your custom button style as used in xml file.

Comment: I cannot see any usage of `com.app.nbhc.utilities.CustomTypefacedButton` this class in your xml file.
Have you extended any of the class with CustomTypefacedButton

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file couldn't find where you have used `CustomTypefacedButton`, so check out how I use it over my [blog](https://medium.com/@jimitpatel/custom-font-views-controls-in-android-f8213c2172a1#.i0dh97la8)

This is what I use, just code, explanation on the blog available -

File - `attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="TextFont">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Class - `FontCache.java`

```
public class FontCache {

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<>();

    /**
     * Gets the typeface from Asset folder
     * @param name path to the font within asset folder
     * @param context context of the view
     * @return
     */
    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if (tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}

/**
 * Sets a font on a TextView
 *
 * @param textview view for which font mentioned needs to be changed
 * @param font path of the font where it has been saved (Generally within asset folder)
 * @param context Context where view has been used
 */
public static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, String font, Context context) {
    if (font == null) {
        return;
    }
    Typeface typeface = FontCache.get(font, context);
    if (typeface != null) {
        textview.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

Class - `CustomFontHelper.java`

```
public class CustomFontHelper {
    /**
     * Sets a font on a textview based on the custom com.my.package:font attribute
     * If the custom font attribute isn't found in the attributes nothing happens
     *
     * @param textview
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextFont);
        String font = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.TextFont_customFont);
        setCustomFont(textview, font, context);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Sets a font on a TextView
     *
     * @param textview view for which font mentioned needs to be changed
     * @param font path of the font where it has been saved (Generally within asset folder)
     * @param context Context where view has been used
     */
    public static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, String font, Context context) {
        if (font == null) {
            return;
        }
        Typeface typeface = FontCache.get(font, context);
        if (typeface != null) {
            textview.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a font on a paint based on the custom com.my.package:font attribute
     * If the custom font attribute isn't found in the attributes nothing happens
     * 
     * @param paint
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public static void setCustomFont(Paint paint, Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextFont);
        String font = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.TextFont_customFont);
        setCustomFont(paint, font, context);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Changing font of Paint element
     * @param paint text element of which font needs to be changed
     * @param font
     * @param context
     */
    public static void setCustomFont(Paint paint, String font, Context context) {
        if (font == null) {
            return;
        }
        Typeface typeface = FontCache.get(font, context);
        if (typeface != null) {
            paint.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}
```

Class - `FontButton.java`

```
public class FontButton extends Button {

    public FontButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }

    public FontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }
}
```

In `string.xml` path of fonts in asset folder

```
<string name="font_light">fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf</string>
<string name="font_semibold">fonts/SourceSansPro-Semibold.ttf</string>
<string name="font_regular">fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf</string>
<string name="font_bold">fonts/Oxygen-Bold.ttf</string>
```

In xml this is how I have used it -

```
<com.COMPANY.APP.app.custom.FontButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lbl_welcome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="YOUR SHOPPING COMPANION!"
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_12"
    app:customFont="@string/font_semibold" />
```

Comment: @user3563459, if you remove first child `RelativeLayout` of `ScrollView` what happens??